# Reformat dataframe in a pivot-like style

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a somewhat involved transformation of my data where I was wondering if someone had a more efficient method than mine. I start with a dataframe as this one:

```
|    | item              |   value |
|---:|:------------------|--------:|
|  0 | WAUZZZF23MN053792 |       0 |
|  1 | A                 |       1 |
|  2 | WF0TK3SS2MMA50940 |       0 |
|  3 | A                 |      10 |
|  4 | B                 |      11 |
|  5 | C                 |      12 |
|  6 | D                 |      13 |
|  7 | E                 |      14 |
|  8 | W0VEAZKXZMJ857138 |       0 |
|  9 | A                 |      20 |
| 10 | B                 |      21 |
| 11 | C                 |      22 |
| 12 | D                 |      23 |
| 13 | E                 |      24 |
| 14 | W0VEAZKXZMJ837930 |       0 |
| 15 | A                 |      30 |
| 16 | B                 |      31 |
| 17 | C                 |      32 |
| 18 | D                 |      33 |
| 19 | E                 |      34 |
```

and I would like to arrive here:

```
|    | item              |   value |   C |
|---:|:------------------|--------:|----:|
|  0 | WAUZZZF23MN053792 |       0 | nan |
|  1 | WF0TK3SS2MMA50940 |       0 |  12 |
|  2 | W0VEAZKXZMJ857138 |       0 |  22 |
|  3 | W0VEAZKXZMJ837930 |       0 |  32 |
```

i.e. for every "long" entry, check if there is an item "C" following, and if so, copy that line's value to the line with the long item.

The ugly way i have done this is the following:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "item": [
            "WAUZZZF23MN053792",
            "A",
            "WF0TK3SS2MMA50940",
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D",
            "E",
            "W0VEAZKXZMJ857138",
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D",
            "E",
            "W0VEAZKXZMJ837930",
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D",
            "E",
        ],
        "value": [
            0,
            1,
            0,
            10,
            11,
            12,
            13,
            14,
            0,
            20,
            21,
            22,
            23,
            24,
            0,
            30,
            31,
            32,
            33,
            33,
        ],
    }
)
def isVIN(x):
    return (len(x) == 17) & (x.upper() == x) & (re.search("\s|O|I", x) is None)

# filter the lines with item=="C" or a VIN in item
x = pd.concat([df, df["item"].rename("group").apply(isVIN).cumsum()], axis=1).loc[
    lambda x: (x["item"] == "C") | (x["item"].apply(isVIN))
]
# pivot the lines where item="C"
y = x.loc[x["item"] == "C"].pivot(columns="item").droplevel(level=1, axis=1)
# and then merge the two:
print(
    x.loc[x["item"].apply(isVIN)]
    .merge(y, on="group", how="left")
    .drop("group", axis=1)
    .rename(columns={"value_y": "C", "value_x": "value"})
    .to_markdown()
)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to make this a bit less ugly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subjectively less ugly

```
mask = df.item.str.len().eq(17)
df.set_index(
    [df.item.where(mask).ffill(), 'item']
)[~mask.to_numpy()].value.unstack()['C'].reset_index()

                item     C
0  W0VEAZKXZMJ837930  32.0
1  W0VEAZKXZMJ857138  22.0
2  WAUZZZF23MN053792   NaN
3  WF0TK3SS2MMA50940  12.0
```

---

A bit more involved but better

```
mask = df.item.str.len().eq(17)
item = df.item.where(mask).pad()
subs = df.item.mask(mask)
valu = df.value

i, r = pd.factorize(item)
j, c = pd.factorize(subs)

a = np.zeros((len(r), len(c)), valu.dtype)

a[i, j] = valu

pd.DataFrame(a, r, c)[['C']].rename_axis('item').reset_index()

                item   C
0  WAUZZZF23MN053792   0
1  WF0TK3SS2MMA50940  12
2  W0VEAZKXZMJ857138  22
3  W0VEAZKXZMJ837930  32
```

Comment: My fav is #1 above.  Still trying to work out why `~mask.to_numpy()` works but `~mask` does not.

Comment: Because pandas wants to align `~mask` on its index and I've already set a different index by that point so it would break.  It's easier to just grab the values in `~mask` so pandas can't do that (-:

Comment: Hi @piRSquared, thanks a lot, I like both solutions!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
# Your conditions vectorized
m = ((df['item'].str.len() == 17)
     & (df['item'].str.upper() == df['item'])
     & (~df['item'].str.contains(r'\s|O|I')))

# Create virtual groups to align rows
df['grp'] = m.cumsum()

# Merge and align rows
out = (pd.concat([df[m].set_index('grp'),
                 df[~m].pivot('grp', 'item', 'value')], axis=1)
         .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                item  value     A     B     C     D     E
0  WAUZZZF23MN053792      0   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1  WF0TK3SS2MMA50940      0  10.0  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0
2  W0VEAZKXZMJ857138      0  20.0  21.0  22.0  23.0  24.0
3  W0VEAZKXZMJ837930      0  30.0  31.0  32.0  33.0  33.0
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are all very nice. For a bit more variety, you could also filter `df` for "long" data and `C` values; `concat`; then "compress" the DataFrame using `groupby` + `first`:

```
out = pd.concat([df[df['item'].str.len()==17], 
                 df.loc[df['item']=='C', ['value']].set_axis(['C'], axis=1)], axis=1)
out = out.groupby(out['item'].str.len().eq(17).cumsum()).first().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
                item  value     C
0  WAUZZZF23MN053792    0.0   NaN
1  WF0TK3SS2MMA50940    0.0  12.0
2  W0VEAZKXZMJ857138    0.0  22.0
3  W0VEAZKXZMJ837930    0.0  32.0
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), a pandas wrapper that reimagines pandas APIs:

###### Construct data

```py
>>> import re
>>> from datar.all import (
...     c, f, LETTERS, tibble, first, cumsum,
...     mutate, group_by, slice, first, pivot_wider, select
... )
>>> 
>>> df = tibble(
...     item=c(
...         "WAUZZZF23MN053792",
...         "A",
...         "WF0TK3SS2MMA50940",
...         LETTERS[:5],
...         "W0VEAZKXZMJ857138",
...         LETTERS[:5],
...         "W0VEAZKXZMJ837930",
...         LETTERS[:5],
...     ),
...     value=c(
...         0, 1,
...         0, f[10:15],
...         0, f[20:25],
...         0, f[30:35],
...     )
... )
>>> df
                 item   value
             <object> <int64>
0   WAUZZZF23MN053792       0
1                   A       1
2   WF0TK3SS2MMA50940       0
3                   A      10
4                   B      11
5                   C      12
6                   D      13
7                   E      14
8   W0VEAZKXZMJ857138       0
9                   A      20
10                  B      21
11                  C      22
12                  D      23
13                  E      24
14  W0VEAZKXZMJ837930       0
15                  A      30
16                  B      31
17                  C      32
18                  D      33
19                  E      34
```

###### Manipulate data

```
>>> def isVIN(x):
...     return len(x) == 17 and x.isupper() and re.search(r"\s|O|I", x) is None
... 
>>> (
...     df 
...     # Mark the VIN groups
...     >> mutate(is_vin=cumsum(f.item.transform(isVIN)))
...     # Group by VINs
...     >> group_by(f.is_vin)
...     # Put the VINs and their values in new columns
...     >> mutate(vin=first(f.item), vin_value=first(f.value))
...     # Exclude VINs in the items
...     >> slice(~c(0))
...     # Get the values of A, B, C ...
...     >> pivot_wider([f.vin, f.vin_value], names_from=f.item, values_from=f.value)
...     # Select and rename columns
...     >> select(item=f.vin, value=f.vin_value, C=f.C)
... )
                item   value         C
            <object> <int64> <float64>
0  W0VEAZKXZMJ837930       0      32.0
1  W0VEAZKXZMJ857138       0      22.0
2  WAUZZZF23MN053792       0       NaN
3  WF0TK3SS2MMA50940       0      12.0
```

Comment: Hi @Panwen Wang, thank you very much, I have not known datar and I browsed through the manual yesterday, I definitely need to have a deeper look at it.